# Error Unabled to add User controls to a form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

I get these two error messages, when trying to add a User Control to a Form.
Worked fine for long, no problems. Now the Design won't show the already added User Controls. Where is the problem? I've heard the Constructor must be untouched if possible and that is not the problem here.

Thanks in advance!

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9IJ2.png)

[Settings.settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2XC7.png)

[Referring to Settings property user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS67T.png)

[Second Error Message when no settings property used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5fpn.png)

Comment: Sounds like something is corrupt. Does the same thing happen in multiple projects? If so, I'd suggest repairing VS.

Comment: Yes it happened to another too. I'll try if repairing works.

Comment: If you would coy and paste the Code and MessageBox strings directly into your Question instead of adding screen shot images, you'd probably improve the readability of your question, I'd say

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the Settings Class because the user value is not retrieved.
Check the value of user.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the Settings - the property exists and should be retrieved the way I referred in the original post. And it still doesn't explain the following errors.